# Application.EnableEvents Sometimes Gets Turned Off Automatically

Tags: excel, vba

Every once in a while, I will find that somehow the `Application.EnableEvents` property gets set to false, requiring me to manually set it back to true in the VBE's Immediate window. The mystery to me is that it is set to false without a VBA error being thrown. Had an error been thrown, I wouldn't have questioned it as much.

Can any of you help me out with possible causes to this? For now, I have no leads.

Contextual information:

- I have not been able to reproduce the error
- Nowhere in my code am I changing `Application.EnableEvents`
- All of my code relies exclusively on events, I don't have any UDFs that I call within worksheet cells
- From what I remember, the VBE was open every time, so I was probably actively developing at the time of the failure.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Add a watch on `Application.EnableEvents`, ensure it is global so set Procedure to `(All Procedures)` and Module `(All Modules)` .  Change the Watch Type to `Break When Value Changes`

Make sure your code is unlocked.  Then run your applciation, the code should should stop on each line when the value changes.  This way, you can double check your code acts as intended.

Incidentally, you an use the RAII design pattern to manage these Application settings.  The [code here uses a RAII design pattern to manage the status bar](https://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2016/09/use-raii-design-pattern-to-tidy-your.html)   Essentially the RAII pattern uses a class and utilizes the destructor to reset a setting.

Answer (score 1):

This setting should never change on its own.  I would check to see if you have another workbook open that is modifying the setting.

To do this Open the VBA editor (Alt-F11) and see what workbooks are open by looking at the project explorer on the left hand side.  Look inside each project for code that is disabling the events.

Also, when you do a search on your project and any other open project, make sure to choose "Current Project" in the find window and search on "EnableEvents"  The current project is not selected by default and you may be missing some code in your search you didn't know about like the workbook startup event.

Comment: this last time it occurred on its own, I only had one workbook open, which I searched. Technically - I had the personal workbook open, but that one doesn't have any references to `EnableEvents`.

Comment: This is the kind of thing that those of us who are providing answers have to consider.  In this case, the culprit is most likely a piece of code that failed and ddin't reset the EnableEvents.